# Is there any version of ethereumjs-testrpc for ethereum classic? How to launch geth --rpc in geth classic version on linux?

Tags: testrpc, ethereum-classic, web3.py

I was wondering if there is any version of that local test version but for ethereum classic.

Another question is, in order to use web3.py and geth in my VPS ubuntu terminal...how can I open a geth --rpc client or something for local test in terminal, because I am used to use geth in windows terminal...but I don´t know how to launch geth in linux terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between ETC and ETH mostly in blockchain history in mainnet, but they use same testnets. In fact ETC default testnet is Morden, but it shouldn't affect your tests anyway.

You can use ethereumjs-testrpc for testing ETC related contracts, and any other tools like truffle.

But if you're looking for alternatives that may give some advantage for ETC project take a look at [SputnikVM Dev](https://github.com/ethereumproject/sputnikvm-dev).

It's based on [SputnikVM](https://github.com/ethereumproject/sputnikvm), and Dev Server is a test server. The advantage that this EVM implementations is going to be a default EVM for ETC, so it's more close to production environment